# how can I communicate between containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im using a container with api gateway in port 80, and I'm needing communicate the api gateway between another containers (all these one using dockerfile and docker-compose). How can I do these others conteiners not expose the port to localhost but communicate internally with the api gateway?

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

**Solution:**

Changed docker-compose file to:

```
version: '3.5'

    services:
      app:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
          - ./:/usr/src/app
          - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        expose:
          - "3000"
        image: api-name-service
        container_name: api-name-service
        networks: 
          - api-network

networks:
  api-network:
       name: api-network-service
```

When the services is in the same network, this services can communicate with service name, like "http://api-name-service:3000".

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking--could you try to rephrase the question?

Comment: Hi @duhaime. I'm needing just one endpoint to connect with external access (my api gateway - port 80). The others containters, with others ports, I'm trying NOT expose this ports for dont have a external connect, but having access between api gateway and these others containers.

Comment: Sorry, this is still not clear to me. You have an API on some host, and want other hosts to be able to communicate with the API, but you don't want to "expose" the ports over which they're communicating? Can you define "expose"? Is this all TCP communication?

Comment: @duhaime sorry about that, and thank you for help me. Imagine that, I have some containers in my localhost. Just one container receive external access. Anothers can't receive external access, but need to communicate internally with this specific container.

Comment: If you are using Docker compose, by default they should be attached to the same overlay network, so they should be able to discover each other by their names, that is, they should be able to communicate each other internally, without being exposed to the exterior. Can you update your question with your `docker-compose.yml` ?

Comment: @gasc question is updated.

Comment: But you are defining only one service, what other containers do you need to communicate to `app`? Where are they defined? If you declare another service next to `app`, they both will be able to discover each other by name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `expose` instead of `ports`:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#expose

For example:

```
services:
    app1:
        expose:
            - "3000"
    app2:
        ...
```

assuming some API on port 3000 in app1, then app2 would be able to access `http://app1:3000/api`

Comment: I do this, and just show the port on docker ps -a (I don't have external access now). But how can my others services call this one?

Answer (score 1):

Use docker network. Here is a very good tutorial on the docker website on how to use networking b/w containers: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/